# find object from Tree or List Hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I am having some class like

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee[] ChildOrg{get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;};
    public string id{get; set;};
}
```

**How can i find particular employee from from its id?**

I tried to use somewhat following function.

```
private static Employee GetNode(Employee objEmployeeList, string id)
{
    if (objEmployeeList.ChildOrg==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    foreach (var item in objEmployeeList.ChildOrg)
    {
        if (item.ID.Equals(id))
        {
            return (objEmployeeList)item;
        }
    }
    foreach (var item in objEmployeeList.ChildOrg)
    {
        return GetNode((objEmployeeList)item, id);
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see i am trying write some recursive function to get the employee.

If you carefully look it just goes to bottom only of first node.

Then it returns null and not going to any other node.

**Please tell me way to correct my function and other ways to accomplish samething using linq?**

**EDIT :-**

**I want to access particular node and it's siblings.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some changes in the class and some changes in the routine.

```
public class Employee
{
    public List<Employee> ChildOrg { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Employee(string id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        ChildOrg = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public Employee AddChildOrg(string id, string name)
    {
        var newEmployee = new Employee(id, name);
        ChildOrg.Add(newEmployee);
        return newEmployee;
    }

    public static Employee GetNode(Employee father, string id)
    {
        if (father != null)
        {
            if (father.Id.Equals(id))
                return father;


            if (father.ChildOrg != null)
                foreach (var child in father.ChildOrg)
                {
                    if (child.Id.Equals(id))
                        return child;

                    var employee = Employee.GetNode(child, id);

                    if (employee != null)
                        return employee;
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And a small test program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee root = new Employee(1.ToString(), "root");
        var e2 = root.AddChildOrg(2.ToString(), "2 second level");
        var e3 = e2.AddChildOrg(3.ToString(), "3 third level");
        var e1 = root.AddChildOrg(4.ToString(), "4 second level");
        var e5 = e1.AddChildOrg(5.ToString(), "5 third level");

        Console.WriteLine("Id 3 -> {0}", Employee.GetNode(root, "3").Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Id 1 -> {0}", Employee.GetNode(root, "1").Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Id 5 -> {0}", Employee.GetNode(root, "5").Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jauch. Yes this is working. I think this is DFS (Depth First Search) am i right?

Comment: Yes :). It is a DFS algorithm

Comment: Thanks! you made my day.

Answer (score 1):

Define a traversal function:

```
public static IEnumerable<Employee> Traverse(Employee employee)
{       
    yield return employee;

    if (employee.ChildOrg == null) yield break;

    var subordinates = employee
                      .ChildOrg
                      .SelectMany(Traverse);

    foreach(var s in subordinates)
        yield return s;
}
```

and then find the matching element:

```
var root = new Employee(...);
...

var searchId = "42";
var employee42 = Traverse(root)
                .Single(e => e.id == searchId);
```

This performs a [Depth-first Pre-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) search.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best approach here is to write a recursive method that returns an `IEnumerable<Employee>` which iterates over all the nodes in the tree.

Given an `Employee` class that looks like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee[] ChildOrg { get; set; }
    public string     name     { get; set; }
    public string     id       { get; set; }
}
```

You can write a recursive enumerator like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Employee> AllEmployees(Employee root)
{
    if (root == null)
        yield break;

    yield return root;

    if (root.ChildOrg == null)
        yield break;

    foreach (var child in root.ChildOrg.SelectMany(AllEmployees))
        yield return child;
}
```

Note that this returns ALL the employees. If you want to filter it by ID, you simply need to filter the enumeration, for example:

```
var allNodesWithIdEndingIn0 = AllEmployees(root).Where(node => node.id.EndsWith("0"));
```

It is much more flexible to return an enumeration of all employees because you can then use Linq to process or filter it as you require.

Here's a complete compilable console app that demonstrates this approach:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee[] ChildOrg { get; set; }
        public string     name     { get; set; }
        public string     id       { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Employee> AllEmployees(Employee root)
        {
            if (root == null)
                yield break;

            yield return root;

            if (root.ChildOrg == null)
                yield break;

            foreach (var child in root.ChildOrg.SelectMany(AllEmployees))
                yield return child;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            Employee root = new Employee  { name = "root", id = "root" };
            createChildren(root, 4, 4, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("All employees:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", AllEmployees(root).Select(node => node.id)));

            Console.WriteLine("\nAll nodes with an id that ends in 0:");
            var allNodesWithIdEndingIn0 = AllEmployees(root).Where(node => node.id.EndsWith("0"));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", allNodesWithIdEndingIn0.Select(node => node.id)));
        }

        private static int createChildren(Employee root, int depth, int width, int count)
        {
            if (depth == 0)
                return count;

            root.ChildOrg = new Employee[width];

            for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
            {
                var node = new Employee { id = count.ToString() };
                root.ChildOrg[i] = node;
                count = createChildren(node, depth-1, width, count+1);
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Accessing the nodes' siblings**

If you want the nodes' siblings, you can return the nodes' parents' `ChildOrg` list.

To do so, I will write a wrapper class called `EmployeeAndParent to contain both a node and its parent.

Here's the modified code. It also demonstrates how to access the siblings of the node with id == "100":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee[] ChildOrg
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeAndParent
    {
        public EmployeeAndParent(Employee employee, Employee parent)
        {
            Employee = employee;
            Parent   = parent;
        }

        public readonly Employee Employee;
        public readonly Employee Parent;
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<EmployeeAndParent> AllEmployees(Employee root, Employee parent)
        {
            if (root == null)
                yield break;

            yield return new EmployeeAndParent(root, parent);

            if (root.ChildOrg == null)
                yield break;

            foreach (var child in root.ChildOrg.SelectMany(child => AllEmployees(child, root)))
                yield return child;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            Employee root = new Employee
            {
                name = "root",
                id = "root"
            };
            createChildren(root, 4, 4, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("All employees:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", AllEmployees(root, null).Select(node => node.Employee.id)));

            Console.WriteLine("\nAll nodes with an id that ends in 0:");
            var allNodesWithIdEndingIn0 = AllEmployees(root, null).Where(node => node.Employee.id.EndsWith("0"));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", allNodesWithIdEndingIn0.Select(node => node.Employee.id)));

            Console.WriteLine("\nAll siblings of the node with id == 100, along with that node itself:");
            var foundNode = AllEmployees(root, null).Single(node => node.Employee.id == "100");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", foundNode.Parent.ChildOrg.Select(node => node.id)));
        }

        private static int createChildren(Employee root, int depth, int width, int count)
        {
            if (depth == 0)
                return count;

            root.ChildOrg = new Employee[width];

            for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
            {
                var node = new Employee
                {
                    id = count.ToString()
                };
                root.ChildOrg[i] = node;
                count = createChildren(node, depth-1, width, count+1);
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Mathew, I think you are creating single IEnumarable and returning it. But after that i also want to access it's siblings? Please can you help me?

Comment: @NiravKamani To get at a node's siblings, we can use that node's parent's `ChildOrg` list. To get at this, we need to modify the code to return the parent as well as each found node. I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Linq...

```
private Employee GetNode(Employee employee, string id)
{
    if (employee.id.Equals(id))
    {
        return employee;
    }
    if (employee.ChildOrg != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in employee.ChildOrg)
        {
            var emp = GetNode(item, id);
            if (emp != null)
                return emp;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The foreach is wrong, if is not employee and is not the first element of the list will return null, the iteration is break on the first element in that case

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        ChildOrg = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public Employee(string toString, string root)
    {
        ChildOrg = new List<Employee>();
        Id = toString;
        Name = root;
    }

    public IList<Employee> ChildOrg { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public static Employee GetNode(Employee e, string theId)
    {
        if (e.Id.Equals(theId))
        {
            return e;
        }

        var employeeInList = (e.ChildOrg == null) ? null : e.ChildOrg.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id.Equals(theId));
        return employeeInList ??
               e.ChildOrg.Select(item => GetNode(item, theId)).FirstOrDefault(employee => employee != null);
    }
}
```

test

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new Employee(1.ToString(), "root");
        var e1 = new Employee(2.ToString(), "1 second level");
        var e2 = new Employee(3.ToString(), "2 third level");
        var e3 = new Employee(4.ToString(), "3 second level");
        var e4 = new Employee(5.ToString(), "4 third level");
        e3.ChildOrg.Add(e4);
        e2.ChildOrg.Add(e3);
        e1.ChildOrg.Add(e2);
        root.ChildOrg.Add(e1);

        Console.WriteLine("Id 3 -> {0}", Employee.GetNode(root, "3").Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Id 1 -> {0}", Employee.GetNode(root, "1").Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Id 5 -> {0}", Employee.GetNode(root, "5").Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: It is also not working it goes to only first node depth level. And finally throws Null Exception.

Comment: If it throws null is because you have null elements on the collection, is that valid?

Comment: Modified minor stuff and added test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private static Employee GetNode(Employee employee, string id){
    if (employee.id == id)        
        return employee;

    if (employee.ChildOrg != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in employee.ChildOrg)
        {
            if(item.id == id)
                return item;

            var child = GetNode(item, id);

            if(child != null)
               return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```